# No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'

Tags: flutter

Can someone help me to solve this error.
I've got no clue why this keeps coming up.

```
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/gradient_app_bar-0.0.1/lib/gradient_app_bar.dart:230:57: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
    final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true);
                                                        ^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1944:24: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ScaffoldState of(BuildContext context) {
                       ^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/gradient_app_bar-0.0.1/lib/gradient_app_bar.dart:450:20: Error: The method 'ancestorRenderObjectOfType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorRenderObjectOfType'.
    return context.ancestorRenderObjectOfType(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to upgrade `gradient_app_bar` package
`gradient_app_bar: ^0.1.3` (the last update for this package was in 2019 in the period of time flutter went to lots of updates)

you can just switch to `new_gradient_app_bar 0.2.0`  it does the same thing
https://pub.dev/packages/new_gradient_app_bar

Comment: new_gradient_app_bar: ^0.2.0 worked for me... Thanks